# Requisições API JavaScript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Estou utilizando a API JavaScript em minha Cloud. Possuo varias portas diferentes com a aplicação de cada cliente, no final tenho algo mais ou menos assim:

clientea.rafaelcloud.com.br e clienteb.rafaelcloud.com.br

Como descrito neste [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update) temos novidades quanto as politicas da API:

> For apps created on or after June 22, 2016
>
> All new domains or Developer Console API projects created on or after June 22, 2016, are subject to the updated policies and limits, as described above and on our Pricing and Plans page.

Primeiramente gostaria de entender se os limites de utilização é baseado nas keys que eu colocar na chamada na aplicação de cada cliente ou no IP da minha Cloud. Digo isso pois estou batendo na utilização limite para plano gratuito, a qual abrange 25 mil requisições/dia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em segundo lugar, gostaria de saber se existe algum log de requisições, algo que eu possa consultar para ver se o limite está sendo atingido por conta de utilização do usuário ou por conta de algum problema. Na minha aplicação utilizo a API para obter o auto preenchimento de endereço e para também, calcular a distância em KM de um ponto ao outro e também para abrir um mapa com a marcação de ponto A e ponto B para endereço de partida e endereço de destino.
Cada um desses itens (auto complete, cálculo de distância, marcas no gráfico) é tratada como uma requisição diferente?

Caso as requisições sejam computadas por key e não por IP, estou cogitando criar um serviço intermediário que receberá a key da aplicação do cliente e devolverá os resultados, assim terei tudo mais organizado e genérico. O meu problema não é repassar um custo ou absorver, é entender como é computado e pensar em uma forma de organizar isso.